# Trying to sort data inside a react table: Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash, ecmascript-5

I am trying to sort the table data based on the field selected from the dropdown. It should alternatively sort between ascending or descending whenever the same field is clicked. I am maintaining a sort object that decides which field is selected and what is the sort order. Then it is sent to lodash `orderBy` with the field and the order. It does not work

This is what I have tried. Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong. Help is really appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-class-component-1n3f9?file=/src/index.js:0-3000

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
import moment from "moment";
import orderby from "lodash.orderby";

const options = [
  { key: 1, text: "Name", value: "name", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 2, text: "Time", value: "time", icon: "sort" },
  { key: 3, text: "Type", value: "type", icon: "sort" }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
      original: [],
      sortObject: { field: "", order: "" }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let list = [
      {
        name: "namev1",
        time: 1583295463213,
        type: 14
      },
      {
        name: "namea2",
        time: 1582885423296,
        type: 15
      },
      {
        name: "namea3",
        time: 1581295463213,
        type: 16
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ list, original: list });
  }

  handleSearch = e => {
    let searchInput = e.target.value;
    let filteredData = this.state.original.filter(value => {
      return (
        value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.type.toString().includes(searchInput.toString())
      );
    });
    this.setState({ list: filteredData });
  };

  formSortObject = fieldName => {
    let { sortObject } = this.state;
    if (!sortObject.field || sortObject.field !== fieldName) {
      Object.assign(sortObject, {
        field: fieldName,
        order: "asc"
      });
      return sortObject;
    } else if (sortObject.field === fieldName) {
      Object.assign(sortObject, {
        ...sortObject,
        order: sortObject.order === "desc" ? "asc" : "desc"
      });
      return sortObject;
    }
  };

  handleSort = (e, data) => {
    let dropdDownValue = data.value;
    let currentField = this.formSortObject(dropdDownValue);
    let result = orderby(
      this.state.list,
      currentField.field,
      currentField.order
    );
    this.setState({ list: result });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        Search: <input type="text" onChange={this.handleSearch} />
        <Dropdown text="Sort By" options={options} onChange={this.handleSort} />
        <h1>List</h1>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.list.map((item, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>
                  <p>{index + 1}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>{item.name}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>{moment().diff(item.time, "days")}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>{item.type}</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isnt's working as you spected because you are calling the `handleSort` function only when the value of the select change (see the `onChange` of your `<Dropdown />`).

**What you need is the function executed when an option is clicked.**

I searched for [the documentation](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-dropdown) of the library you are using and I came to the conclusion that what you need is this.

```
    <Dropdown text='Sort By'>
        <Dropdown.Menu>
          {options.map(item=>
            <Dropdown.Item text={item.text} value={item.value} icon={item.icon} key={item.key} onClick={this.handleSort}/>
          )}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
```

I tried it in your codesandbox and it works perfectly!

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks much! It helped. Also how could I set the indicator inside the drop-down so that it shows on what order the current filed is sorted?

Comment: Changing the value of icon when its clicked.
https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/icon/